# Design of Java RMI-Application

Tags: java, rmi

I got a question about a concrete design of a java RMI-Application. I am at the beginning of learing how to work with rmi. I have a small app: a small stock exchange app. So there is the stock exchange class and for everybody a depot class. The depot class has a reference to the market. The market class has a function to create a depot (it returns a new depot). I would like to design the application in that way, that the remote client can get a reference of his own depot and all clients share the stock market class (so there shall be only one object to the run-time).

I need to design a interface which extends the interface "remote". This interface describes the functions, which the client can call. But what about the classes stock exchange and depot? do they need to implement or extend a class to get the rmi work?

In my interface there is a function, which opens a new depot and returns a depot object. But when I call that function, there is a exception:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1 cannot be cast to depot

Answer (score 1):

With a RMI remote object you can't cast to the concrete class Depot. You have to cast to the remote interface.

Comment: Yes, exactly. But there is a function in the remote-interface, where I want to return a reference to a personal depot. And there is the exception and I dont know how to treat that.

Comment: So yes exactly you are making precisely the mistake described in this answer with the `Depot` object. As it is clearly an exported remote object, it is supplied as its own stub.

Answer (score -1):

You need two interfaces, `StockExchange` and `Depot`. Each of these interfaces should extend `Remote`. But only an instance of a class that implements `StockExchange` will be bound in the RMI registry. Clients will first lookup up the `StockExchange` in the RMI registry using its name. From it, they will call a suitable remote method to get a reference to their own `Depot`.

Comment: Only an instance of a *stub* that implements the same remote interface as the implementation class is bound in the Registry. The implementation-class object never leaves the JVNM it was exported from.

Comment: @EJB I never said it did.

Comment: 'But only an instance of a class that implements StockExchange will be bound in the RMI registry.'. It's wrong, and it's impossible unless that instance leaves the JVM and enters the Registry, which isn't what happens.

Comment: @EJP I see. I didn't mean that the remote object literally somehow migrated to the registry, I was simply distinguishing which of his remote objects should be passed to `Registry.bind()`. Regarding your first comment, I would have guessed that the stub is generated dynamically on the client using meta-data from the registry. Is there actually an instance of the stub in the registry? What purpose does it serve?